# A better way to extract the value of a field within an Option[JsValue] in scala?

Tags: json, scala, pattern-matching, option-type

I have a value in a JsObject which I want to assign to a specific key in Map, and I want to ask if there is a better way to extract that value without using a case matcher.

I have access to a **request** variable which is a case class that has a parameter **myData**

**myData** is an Option[JsValue] which contains multiple fields and I want to return the boolean value of one specific field in there called **“myField”** in a string format. The below works, but I want to find a more succinct way of getting the value of **"myField"** without case matching.

```
val newMap =
Map(
“myNewKey” -> request.myData.map(_ match {
case JsObject(fields) => fields.getOrElse(“myField”, "unknown").toString
case _ => “unknown”})
```

The output would then be

```
"myField": "true"
```

or

```
"myField": "false"
```

or if it isn't true or false, i.e the field doesn't exist

```
"myField": "unknown"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather:

```
myMap ++ (request.myData \ "myField").validateOpt[String].asOpt.
  toSeq.collect { // to map entries
   case Some(str) => "keyInMap" -> str
  }
```

> Do not use `.toString` to convert a JSON value or pretty print it.